# Entity Y has 2 FK to entiy X not working with EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I had this code working using EF5, not is complains about cyclic dependencies:

```
 public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SupplierId")]
    public Company SupplierE { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    [InverseProperty("Suppliers")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}

 public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Company")]
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Company")]
    public ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

}
```

and the fluent configuration is something like:

```
  modelBuilder
         .Entity<Supplier>()
         .HasRequired(c => c.Company)
         .WithMany(v => v.Suppliers)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Also I have some code to configure the keys fr the Supplier Entity:

```
public class SupplierConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
{
    public SupplierConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => new {c.CompanyId, c.SupplierId});
    }
}
```

I get an error message about cyclic dependencies:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Supplier_dbo.Company_CompanyId' on table 'Supplier' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

As I mentionned this used to work in EF5, I just migrated to EF6 and started getting this.In addition I have a similar class called `Client` and it works fine for it.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

this is the same code from client:

```
public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Company ClientE { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        [InverseProperty("Clients")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You have supplier entity that consists Company Entity that has list of  supplier entity. Don't think it can work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It is a basic One-to-Many.

Comment: Can you write down this "same but works" `Client` entity too?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan I have the same configuration for the Client Entity, but I don't get the same error message.

Comment: when is the error raised? I doubt that the error should also occur to `Client`, maybe it's not the turn of `Client`. It's likely that when the error  occurred on `Supplier` is raised, it won't check if there is something wrong with `Client`. I hope you understand what I mean. I can see the circular references here, it's correct when raising the error.

Comment: @Hopeless It happens when I run Update-Database -f. Where do you see the circular references? can you post the code as new code?

Comment: sorry I was wrong about circular references, the exception mentioned about ***multiple cascade paths***, maybe that's the case. But really I don't see the issue with what you posted.